# Simple, cross-platform to get well-known desktop paths in Java?

Tags: java, settings, desktop, freedesktop.org

I'm looking for a simple, cross-platform way, on the JVM, to get the appropriate directories for storing application settings and cache data. E.g., on Linux under the XDG specs:

- config in `~/.config/appname`
- cache in `~/.cache/appname`

Windows stuff goes in `C\Users\user\Application Data` or some such (on Win 7); I gather that Mac puts stuff under `~/Library/Application Settings`.

Is there a cross-platform call to get these path locations? I haven't been able to find one, though I find several questions asking about it. Is there some library that has implemented the correct logic for most common desktop platforms?

Worst case, I can just look up `user.home` and pretend everything is an XDG-based Linux environment. But if it's easy to get the right directories for the user's OS, I'd like to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The `FileSystemView` class is the only one I know that contains access to some general directories like this, and is cross-platform. Refer to the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html)

This class contains some method that might be helpful, such as `getHomeDirectory()` and `getDefaultDirectory()`. This class is used by the `JFileChooser` for Swing interfaces. I know it doesn't directly point to the config and cache directories, but it might be a step in the right direction for you.

For my own apps, I take the next-best approach by trying to make all the config and settings contained within the application itself - ie. create a "config" directory under the directory where the application is installed. Even though its not a central location for config for the whole OS, at least it keeps it within the java application context.

Answer (score 2):

We basically set up a utility class that provides this information, mostly based on the `user.home` and `os.name` system property.

We have a series of methods that allow us to build up a path location, something like...

```
SystemUtilities.getApplicationSettingsPath("Name of my awesome app");
```